# Is there any concise way to convert the type from `Int` to `Double` after applying `splitAt` to a `List`?

Tags: scala

My input is like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 44 33
```

and the result I would like to get is like this:

```
val listA = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
val listB = List(44.0, 33.0)
```

I know I can split a list using `splitAt` but I need the values of ListB to be the type of `Double` because I’m gonna use them in `/` operator.

so far my code is like this, and it’s ugly.

```
val (listA, listB) = li.splitAt(5)
val result = listA.sum * (listB(0).toDouble / (listB(0).toDouble + listB(1).toDouble))
```

Is there any better way to archive my wish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` `listB` to contain `Double`s:

```
val listBDouble = listB.map(_.toDouble)
```

After this you can use this in your expression:

```
val result = listA.sum * (listBDouble(0) / (listBDouble(0) + listBDouble(1)))
```

BTW, if you need having `Double`s only because of the division, probably this is preferred:

```
 val result = listA.sum * ((listB(0): Double) / (listB(0) + listB(1)))
```

This way you ascribe (`: Double`) the nominator to be `Double` and the rest will work as expected.

Comment: I was looking for the way not to use an extra line, and your BTW answer was what I was looking for. Thanks!